# Activesheet."SomeRange".RemoveDuplicates returns error if not "specific" range

Tags: excel, vba

If I specify the range specifically such as:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C3","G20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

the code works perfectly. However, if I instead try to use:

```
ActiveSheet.Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

or

```
Dim selRange as Range
Set selRange = Selection
ActiveSheet.selRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

it doesn't work. I get

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

I cannot use a specific range since it changes all the time so I need to just remove duplicates for the current selection. Does anyone have any tips to solve this?

Comment: The problem is not that there is no `RemoveDuplicates` for `ActiveSheet.Selection` but that ther is no `ActiveSheet.Selection`. Use `Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo` without the `ActiveSheet.`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

The key is adding the `.Address`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

without the `ActiveSheet.` [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel) does not have a `Selection` property/method.